# Oracle: Global namespace qualifier for function?

Tags: oracle, plsql, namespaces

How do I qualify a function or procedure call to indicate that it
should be at global scope?  I have my own scn_to_timestamp()
in a package that needs to call the default global function of
the same name.

```
create or replace package px as
    function scn_to_timestamp(scn number) return timestamp;
end px;

create or replace package body px as
    function scn_to_timestamp(scn number) return timestamp is
    begin
        -- how do I qualify this to refer to the global function?
        return scn_to_timestamp(scn);
    end;
end px;
```

**update:** It turns out there's no such thing as a "global" function, since all functions exist under a schema.  What appears as a global is actually a public synonym, so all you have to do is prefix the call with the schema that exported the function, in this case:

```
        return sys.scn_to_timestamp(scn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the schema name to refer to the global.
I used the schema owner.

```
create or replace package px as
    function scn_to_timestamp(scn number) return timestamp;
end px;

create or replace package body px as
    function scn_to_timestamp(scn number) return timestamp is
    begin
        -- how do I qualify this to refer to the global function?
        return sys.scn_to_timestamp(scn);
    end;
end px;
```

Comment: thanks.  scn_to_timestamp is owned by sys, so I updated to reflect.